# Syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) on javascript including Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

while calling following URL

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('public/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js')}}"></script>
```

it showing

> syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting ',' or ')'
>   (View:

and tried after removing the public, the result is same. In this same blade I include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('public/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css')}}">

<img src="{{ URL::asset('public/dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg')}}" alt="User Avatar" class="img-size-50 mr-3 img-circle">
```

Its working fine, no problem. only while including .js file it showing this error

Comment: you know you get a line number for the error right?

Comment: yes I know which line is that  <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="{{ URL::asset('plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js')); ?>"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->

Comment: and there is no closing `}}` in what you just put in your comment ... you need to provide what is happening before and after this line ... add to your question not in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways to call assets in laravel, 
some time URL calling give unappropriated error

```
href="{{ URL::asset('public/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"
```

better way to use following syntax for avoiding error

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('public/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') !!}"></script>

<link href="{!! asset('public/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css') !!}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

it is recommended from most of developers.

Comment: can you explain how this is different than what they have and how it would resolve their error?

Comment: src="{!! assetasset('   two times assetasset?

Comment: Thanks bro its working.   but there is only one asset     src="{!! asset('public/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') !!}"                 Whats the difference between this and otherone?

Comment: @lagbox its a laravel syntax for calling a JS file

Comment: how is it different than what they have? why is this correct but what they had isn't , etc etc ... explain it in the answer, it isn't for me

Comment: @TestCheck you don't need to specify URL for calling in laravel

Comment: `URL::asset()` is the same as `asset()`, they are the same

Comment: There are so many ways to call assets in laravel, sometime URL::asset() give unappropriated error, better way is using this for call !! asset('public/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') !! @TestCheck

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('public/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Try like this

```
<script src="{{ asset('your-path-excluding-public') }}">
```

Comment: can you explain how that would resolve the error they are getting?

Comment: I Tried but getting syntax error, unexpected 'plugins' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'